# Convert long list of data to colums in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pdf that i need converted to an excel spreadsheet.  I have been able to get the raw data from it and import it into excel, but i am having trouble importing the data how i need it.

My excel sheet now looks like

```
Name 
Address 
Email 
Website 
Name 2 
Address 2  
Email 2  
Website 2 
Name 3 
Address 3 
Email 3 
Website 3 
etc.
```

I need it to look like

```
Name    Address    Email    Website
Name 2  Address 2  Email 2  Website 2
Name 3  Address 3  Email 3  Website 3
```

I have tried to add a comma to the end of every line in word and then import, but it didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!  The list is VERY long.

Answer (score 6):

With data in column **A**, pick any cell not in column **A** and enter:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(4*ROWS($1:1)-4)+(COLUMNS($A:A)),1)
```

Copy this cell both across and down:

[image]

Comment: Wow - cool!  Can you explain the syntax?

Comment: @AdamThe formula creates a pattern of indices to map a single column into a matrix.  **Any single column can be mapped into a 2-D table by adjusting the formula.**................. *There are similar formulas to map any 2-D table into a single column as well.*

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in Notepad++.

Paste the whole thing into np++

I understand it will look like this:

```
Name 
Address 
Email 
Website 
Name 2 
Address 2  
Email 2  
Website 2 
Name 3 
Address 3 
Email 3 
Website 3 
etc.
```

Now do a find replace to replace `\r\nAddress` with `\t Address`.

[image: Before Find/Replace]  Note that "Extended" search mode is selected in the lower left.

`\r\n` is the standard new line notation in windows.  `\t` is a tab.

Your data should now look like this:

```
Name   Address 
Email 
Website 
Name 2   Address 2  
Email 2  
Website 2 
Name 3    Address 3 
Email 3 
Website 3 
etc.
```

[image: After Find/Replace]
Repeat the find replace to strip the new lines and put in commas in front of *email* and *Website* too.  Now you have a tab separated file that you can paste into Excel.